# How can I practice aiming faster as Sniper?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-sniper

I have noticed that when I play sniper if my shots miss, it's usually because I fail to actually get it to the right spot in time.

I also can't seem to get a good shot if I go too fast.

I also seem to shoot slowly in the flash game shoot which I have been using to see how my aimbooster practice is going.

Here is an example of the fast shooting

Answer (score 3):

There are countless tutorials on YouTube covering this subject, but the only one that really stuck out to me was nst's tutorial.

**Prediction**
 - Shoot an enemy when they are unlikely to change direction. This will allow you line up for a headshot.
 - Enemies' movements are somewhat easier to predict if they jump. Shoot where you think the enemy will land rather than where the enemy is.
 - Not all classes die from one hit, if you landed a successful headshot try finishing them off with a noscope.
 - Check for enemy snipers, most will be at commonly known spots so make sure to check those before you push.
 - Parachuting soldiers are an easy kill since they are hindered by their lack of mobility.
 - In a Sniper v Sniper. A common tactic to use is "Doublezooming". Doublezooming is used after a player has missed their shot, they will instantly zoom in/out to bait the enemy player into thinking they are going to take a shot. When the enemy sniper zooms in they will not be able to move around as much and therefore makes it an easier target to kill.

**Make The Best Of What You Got**
 - In a scenario where you are likely to die, it always good to try and get a pick. Remember medics take priority over any other class.

**Play Around Corners**
 - Hold angles where you think the enemies are likely to come. This will allow you to fully power up your shot before an enemy comes.
 - Aim at the wall when you are scoped in. So the sniper dot will not be visible to enemies and you will catch them by surprise.

**Don't Be Afraid To Take A Fight**
 - The sniper rifle is powerful at close ranges. Don't be afraid to take a chance at a shot.

**Sensitivity**
 - While it's up to your personal preference. A good sensitivity for sniper is a low one.
 - High perfect mouse control speed is recommended. Meaning no matter how fast you move your mouse it will always move the same distance in-game.

The video in your question doesn't necessarily represent the true nature of the game as you will zoom out after each shot hence why I summarised it. You gotta learn how to walk before you can run.

Comment: Hi Mano!  Can you give a small example from the video as well?  It would greatly improve your answer!

Comment: Oh, yes perhaps I could improve it. I will try to the best of my ability, but not right now. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you try [this site](http://aim400kg.com/) specifically [Fast Shooting](http://aim400kg.com/fa/)I use it on a constant basis and I have improved dramatically because of it. It provides a great resource with a cornucopia of minigames that each target a specific area of skill

Comment: This constitutes a link only answer, and will become invalid as soon as the site goes down. Please summarize the relevant info from the link to ensure your answer remains valid.